# How to avoid the Geofences limit of 5 per app

Tags: android, geolocation, android-geofence

Anddroid allows to have 100 Geofences per device, but it also has a limit of 5 different PendingIntents.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes.html#GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS

This means that my application can only have 5 Geofences?
Any method I can circumvent this limit?

Comment: `Anddroid allows to have 100 Geofences per device, `?? Why only 100? Does not make sense. And what has Android to do with geofences?

Comment: Not sure why they are limiting to 100. But thats what it is: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Android limits? Dont think so. Who are `they`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found the workaround to be using the same request ID for the pending intents.

I used to create a different Pending intent (different request ID) for each Geofence request, but now I changed to use the same pending intent but differentiate by the received Geofences using  `List<Geofence> getTriggeringGeofences ()`